# Convert IEnumerable<T> into a List<SomeObject>

Tags: c#

So I'm building a small application in C# where I have an IEnumerable that I want to cast into a List. This is what I got:

```
var enumerable = SettingsManager.ReadSettings();
var list = enumerable.Cast<Setting>().ToList();
```

The compiler says that ReadSettings cannot be inferred from the usage. 
This is how ReadSettings look like:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ReadSettings<T>()
{
     //Code omitted
     return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T[]>(fileAsString).ToList<T>();
}
```

Comment: You are not giving a type to 'ReadSettings<>()' when you are setting 'enumerable'

Comment: When using Newtonsoft.Json serializer, you can replace `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T[]>(fileAsString).ToList<T>()` by `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(fileAsString)` or even `IList<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>`

Answer (score 7):

If your method is generic, you should *provide* a generic type-parameter. From your usage I suppose you´re after the type `Setting`, so your correct code was something like this:

```
var enumerable = SettingsManager.ReadSettings<Setting>();
var list = enumerable.ToList();
```

Now `enumerable` has a strong type known at *compile*-time, which is why you can omit casting every element within that list to the `Setting`-type.

If you don´t know the actual type at runtime you´re stuck on using reflection as mentioned [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method).

EDIT: As your `ReadSettings`-method actually produces a list by calling `ToList` you could omit the explicit second `ToList`-call on the second line and cast to `List<T>` instead. Alternativly - and imho better - was to omit that call within `ReadSettings`.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing `T` specification for `ReadSetting`. You need code like this:

```
var list= SettingsManager.ReadSettings<Setting>();
// continue here
```

Comment: This will give OP an `IEnumerable<T>`, not a `List<T>`

Comment: @DavidG I believe calling `ToList()` depends on further usage. And since OP used this method, I didn't include it in my code.

Comment: @DavidG And their example code specifically creates a list from the enumerable on the very next line.  This code corrects the error, and the resulting code does exactly what the user asked for.

Comment: @DavidG well, if you look on `ReadSettings` method, there is already one `ToList`. I don't see any example why create data, take them to List, then use them as IEnumerable and then taking it to List again.

Comment: @BradleyUffner But this answer goes directly to the `list` variable and combines both lines form the question.

Comment: @PavelPájaHalbich But the return type of the method is `IEnumerable` so while you've created a `List`, it's stored in a different type.